# Two Tables & Ordering By Column Not in Both

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-order-by, union

I have two tables.. one for a player's session.. and one for the player's character. I can't change how the tables record data.. so I have to work with these. Ultimately, I am trying to create a "who is online" list and need some help figuring out how to sort it all.

account sessions (if a row is present in this list, account is logged in)

```
----------------------
| accountid | charid |
----------------------
| 1001      | 2001   |
----------------------
| 1004      | 2006   |
----------------------
| 1002      | 2003   |
----------------------
```

characters (shows all characters active or not)

```
------------------------------------
| charid    | accountid | charname |
------------------------------------
| 1001      | 2001      | user1    |
------------------------------------
| 1002      | 2001      | user2    |
------------------------------------
| 1003      | 2002      | user3    |
------------------------------------
| 1004      | 2002      | user4    |
------------------------------------
| 1005      | 2003      | user5    |
------------------------------------
| 1006      | 2004      | user6    |
------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to order by online followed by character name. So according to those tables.. I'd want a printout like this:

ONLINE
user1
user3
user6

OFFLINE
user2
user4
user5

What query do I use to print out data like that when it uses two tables and sorting by the second table character names.. and whether or not they're online- two different sorting from two different tables?

If there were character names in the session table.. it'd make this a whole lot easier.. but I don't think I can change that myself. :( Any help?

Comment: your charid and accountid are flipped in the two tables

Comment: That's just how they are in the tables. There's a session table showing the accounts- purely to determine if they're logged in and which character they are playing. Then the character table shows additional information about that character. Even if I switched the two columns around.. still have no idea how to sort them the way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT      charname, IF(sessions.charid IS NULL, 'offline', 'online') as status
FROM        characters
LEFT JOIN   sessions
ON          characters.charid=sessions.charid
AND         characters.accountid=sessions.accountid
ORDER BY    status DESC, charname ASC
```

This should give you a two column table with charname and status, online first. 
You could get fancier with the GROUP_CONCAT function too